# How start Emacs only with specific packages?

Tags: package, autoload, require

Linux Mint 20,
Emacs 27.1

In my init.el file I loaded many packages.

But sometime I need to load only some specific packages.

E.g.

```
emacs -Q and only vertico+marginalia+theme
```

The question is: How I can start Emacs only with specific packages?

P.S.

Example of my init.el

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(require 'dired-narrow)


(dired-recent-mode 1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+")
(require 'dired+)

(require 'highlight-symbol)
```

Comment: I don't really understand where the issue is. You can name this initialization file "my-specific-init.el" and start emacs with the command "emacs -Q -l my-specific-init.el

Answer (score 1):

If you use `require` in your init file, then Emacs must load the package. If you don’t use `require`, then Emacs doesn’t need to load anything. The mistake most people make is to `require` every package that they want to use.

99% of the time you can configure any package you want (by setting its variables, for example), without ever `require`ing the package. The package will not actually be loaded until you start calling any of the functions it defines. Emacs has a big list of `autoload`ed functions that tells it what files to load when one of them is called.

Comment: +1. Just  comment (for other readers) to add that you can also "soft-require" a package, meaning that if it's not in your `load-path` then it's a no-op instead of raising an error. To do that, add a non-`nil` 3rd arg: `(require 'foo nil t)`.